# Intuition behind the 2D heat equation and examining numerical solutions through inspection

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the 2-D heat equation $\frac{\partial u(x,y,t)}{\partial t}=\nabla^2 u(x,y,t)$ by approximating the spatial differential operator i.e $\nabla^2 u$. The approximation yields a differentiation matrix too large to post here. I solved the system of ODEs by decomposing the matrix into its eigensystem. A similar approach to what has been done [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4428618/#R23).

The initial  conditions are shown to be satisfied below.

[image]

The problem I encounter is that when I step the solution in time the boundary values 'blow up' and 'cold spot' migrates to the center of the domain for all time.

[image]

I simply expected the temperature to smooth out and form a level surface. Does this look like a possible solution or is it clear there must be a large numerical error evolved. Would one ever expect this sought of surface to satisfy the heat equation, I get the feeling its just not 'right'.

The initial conditions I used where generated in Mathematica and are about 441 equations, for example below are the first 5.

- u[0., 0., 0.] == 0.01
- u[0., 0.1, 0.] == 0.02
- u[0., 0.2, 0.] == 0.03
- u[0., 0.3, 0.] == 0.04
- u[0., 0.4, 0.] == 0.05

Comment: Could you please post the equation you're solving? Domain/Source/Boundary conditions/initial conditions/...

Comment: Sure, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\nabla^2 u$. There are no boundary conditions since if $\nabla^2 u$ is approximated by some differential matrix you are left with a system of ODEs in $t$. The initial conditions are specified for each nodal point and are a bit of a mouthful.I shall add them to the question.

Comment: you can add gifs just as if they were image files, maybe you meant how to construct a gif from your images?

Comment: Sure, let me clarify. How would you expect the surface in the first image to evolve if it was a solution to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\nabla^2 u$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying there are no boundary conditions.  When the matrix is formed for the numerical approximation, it incorporates the boundary conditions.  So when you form the matrix you already know if it is Dirichlet or Neumann. If you post the BCs as well as your matrix, it can be examined for what the issue might be. No, the solution in the movie is definitely not a heat equation solution.  A further guess is that there may be a sign error (gradients being steepened instead of smoothed).

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem too far off what I'd expect the solution with these increasing boundary conditions to look like. @user423573 the issue is almost certainly with what you are doing at the boundary, since things  seem fairly smooth in the interior.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis and Mathemagical are correct, the boundary conditions of course had to be included.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was no, one should expect smoothing along the boundaries. This is not an intuitive solution to the heat equation for reasons better outlined in a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/simple-solution-to-diffusion-equation)